# "The idea of the X came from Y" vs "The idea of the X raised from Y"

Tags: british-english, sentence, science

I'm confiused a little bit in a correct usage of the word **idea** in sentences. Wich one of the following correct?

> The idea of the system design came from the knowledge acquired in literature review and analysis of the current trends of workplace learning.

or

> The idea of the system design raised from the knowledge acquired in literature review and analysis of the current trends of workplace learning.

If both are wrong, the any other suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first one is Correct.

*The idea of the system design came from the knowledge acquired in literature review and analysis of the current trends of workplace learning.*

because Ideas originated by reading , analysis or when we do something.

Comment: Thanks. I also end up with first version. Lets wait until other people write their opinions. If not this answer will be accepted ;)